# "-bash: {}: No such file or directory" using find exec

Tags: find, gzip

I'm trying to run `find . -name "binaries.tgz.*.gz" -exec gzip -d -k < {} \;` (ultimately I'm trying to run `find . -name "binaries.tgz.*.gz" -type f -exec gzip -d -k < {} \; | tar tzf -` but I'm trying to figure out why the command before the pipe isn't working first), but I get the following error:

> `-bash: {}: No such file or directory`:

```
[user@host:/data/dionaea]$ find . -name "binaries.tgz.*.gz" -type f -exec gzip -d -k < {} \;
-bash: {}: No such file or directory
[user@host:/data/dionaea]$ ls | grep binaries
binaries
binaries.tgz
binaries.tgz.10.gz
binaries.tgz.11.gz
binaries.tgz.12.gz
binaries.tgz.13.gz
binaries.tgz.14.gz
binaries.tgz.15.gz
binaries.tgz.16.gz
binaries.tgz.17
binaries.tgz.17.gz
binaries.tgz.18.gz
binaries.tgz.19.gz
binaries.tgz.1.gz
binaries.tgz.20.gz
binaries.tgz.21.gz
binaries.tgz.22.gz
binaries.tgz.23.gz
binaries.tgz.24.gz
binaries.tgz.25.gz
binaries.tgz.26.gz
binaries.tgz.27.gz
binaries.tgz.28.gz
binaries.tgz.29.gz
binaries.tgz.2.gz
binaries.tgz.30.gz
binaries.tgz.3.gz
binaries.tgz.4.gz
binaries.tgz.5.gz
binaries.tgz.6.gz
binaries.tgz.7.gz
binaries.tgz.8.gz
binaries.tgz.9.gz
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting the `<` redirection to do here? `gzip` can read from a named file directly (and `-exec` can't - you'd need to wrap that in a `sh -c ' ... '` or equivalent)

Comment: It's a weird situation where a `tar.gz` archive has been compressed again into a `gz` file, so I need the `<` redirection so I can pipe the output into the subsequent `tar` command to extract it in one go. Thanks for the heads up about wrapping it in a `sh -c` - I didn't know `find -exec` couldn't read from that redirection. I'll give that a go

Comment: Yep - that works. Thanks @steeldriver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your command

```
find . -name "binaries.tgz.*.gz" -exec gzip -d -k < {} \;
```

the `< {}` is interpreted by the shell before running `find`.

Use

```
find . -name "binaries.tgz.*.gz" -exec gzip -d -k {} \;
```

to extract all files and keep the original ones.

You can try

```
find . -name "binaries.tgz.*.gz" -type f -exec gzip -d -c {} \; | tar tzf -
```

to extract to stdout, but you cannot be sure that the files will get processed by `find` in the correct order.